# How to use PKPaymentButton in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a page in Xamarin.Forms in which I have to show PKPaymentButton by using the same PKPaymentButton class which is a child of UIButton in PassKit.
I have written a custom ButtonRenderer and trying to convert the button into PKPayment button. 
I got so far that in custom renderer we can change the appearance of a button but can we use something like creating a new button instance in my case PKPaymentButton and replace it with Button.

UPDATE-
I have achieved this by-

```
public class ApplePayButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            var button = new PKPaymentButton(PKPaymentButtonType.Buy, PKPaymentButtonStyle.Black);
            SetNativeControl(button);                
        }
    }


}
```

Now I am trying to get its click into Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Do you want me to give you an example of how to take your event back to XF?

Answer (score -1):

You could use **Messaging Center** to send message when you click the payment Button.

#### in Custom Renderer

```
var button = new PKPaymentButton(PKPaymentButtonType.Buy, PKPaymentButtonStyle.Black);
button.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
SetNativeControl(button);
```

```
private void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this,"PayButtonClick");
}
```

#### in Forms

Add the following code to the constructor of the ContentPage which contains the Payment Button

```
public xxxPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "PayButtonClick",(args)=> {


    //do some thing you want

   });

}
```

Comment: Would it not make sense to have a delegate event combination here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/

Comment: A more straightforward way to accomplish this (without using MessagingCenter) is just to include a command on the button itself, and then invoke that command when the touch up inside event is occurring. (In the renderer) 
```// This occurs when the button is tapped.
                button.TouchUpInside += ( sender, e ) =>
                {
                    if( Element is PaymentButton paymentButton )
                    {
                        paymentButton.PaymentStartedCommand.Execute( null );
                    }
                };```